# Switch state not changing on tap

Tags: flutter

I want to change the state of switch when tapped but it does not change. The state is changed only when I drag the switch tile button.

````
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 12.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Switch(
                            value: switchValue,
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                switchValue = value;
                              });
                            }),
                        Text(
                          "Check-in",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )```
````

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the piece of code you've entered here... maybe if you provide the complete class code, it would be more clear to address the problem

Comment: Maybe you didn't define the `switchValue` as a global field in your `State` class...

Comment: Yes, I defined it inside the build function but it should have been outside the build. That was the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to move the setState() outside of the Slider and before the build (as shown below) to get it to work

```
  bool switchValue = false;
  void _changeSwitch(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      switchValue = !switchValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

...

```
 Switch(value: switchValue, onChanged: _changeSwitch),
```

More details on using setState() if you're interested: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-state-management-setstate-fn-is-the-easiest-and-the-most-powerful-44703c97f035

Comment: I solved it by removing the initially defined switch value outside of the build function. 
`
class _ScheduleRowState extends State<ScheduleRow> {
  final double dotSize = 12.0;
  bool switchValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
`